# How can I attach custom toggle controls to a checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a little slide toggle control to use for my checkboxes in my app. Here is a link to the controls.

http://codepen.io/spstratis/pen/fJvoH

I would like to some attach the the switches to control an html checkbox .

I have a method implemented currently at this time, but it's using images to handle the slider look and feel and that isn't working for what I need to do with the app any longer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your toggle function you just need to target a checkbox, something like this:

```
$($(button).data("targetCheckbox")).prop("checked", true);
```

where you have already set `$(button).data("targetCheckbox")` to be the checkbox element targeted by that button

Comment: I found that just doing $('.checkboxElement').prop("checked", true); worked for me. Could you explain what using the .data() method in your example does? I'm assuming it is a better implementation than my own.

Comment: it allows you to use the same method for multiple different checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

```
this link will help you, you can control check box using this script

http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/
```

Comment: In this situation I'm really wanting to avoid the use of a plugin. I also would need to keep the controls styled exactly how I have them currently.

Comment: Then again I could always fork this plugin and alter it to my needs.